# Replace a color using Wand

Tags: python, replace, colors, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to replace a color in an image with another color, by defining the coordinates of one of its pixels.
But when I run the code the result is exactly the same as the original.

here's the original image:

[image]

here's the code:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

with Drawing() as draw:
    draw.fill_color = Color('#ff0000')
    draw.color(192,84,'replace')

    with Image(filename='rgb.jpg') as img:
        img.save(filename='rgr.jpg')
        display(img)
```

192,84 is somewhere around the middle of the blue section of the image.
Which should now be red, except nothing changes.
I thought maybe it has something to do with the "fuzz" but i can't figure out the syntax. I tried:

```
draw.color(192,84,'replace',fuzz=10)
```

But I got the "unexpected keyword argument 'fuzz'" error.

so I tried:

```
draw.fuzz = 10
```

I got no errors, but the image still had no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you did not apply the drawing context to the image.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

with Drawing() as draw:
    draw.fill_color = Color('#ff0000')
    draw.color(192,84,'replace')

    with Image(filename='gb.jpg') as img:
        draw(img)  # <= here
        img.save(filename='rgr.jpg')
        display(omg)
```

[image: Replace a color using Wand]